# How to load a table from a .nib when an item in a previous table is selected?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios4

At the moment, I have an iOS app that starts out with a NavigationView (root view) and a table contained in the root view below the navigation bar. I am attempting to load another view (hoping to make it another table) from a .nib file when the first row in the original table is selected. How can I do this?

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the `UITableViewDelegate` method, `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Ensure that your tableview's delegate is set to your view controller inside Interface Builder, or if you are not using interface builder..

```
[tableView setDelegate:self];
```

Your view controller will then adopt the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol and respond to `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` when a row is selected.

Loading your new view when the first row is selected will be implemented like so..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(indexPath.section == 0){ // the first row

        MyView *myView = [[MyView alloc] init];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:myView animated:YES];

        [myView release];

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you - This is exactly what I have. For some reason, however, my app crashes when I select the row and doesn't load the view.

Comment: The row gets selected perfectly fine in the first view, but the second view doesn't load and then the app crashes.